# Why doesn't my wordpress website open in Internet Explorer?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Why doesn't my `Wordpress` website open in Internet Explorer? It takes much time and my system hangs up.

my site [url](http://www.clerisysolutions.com/cs/endurocross/).

Comment: Could be one of a million things.... -1

Comment: Could you maybe show us what it is actually doing, or what it should be doing?

Comment: Your website is extremely slow. maybe it takes to long for internet explorer to load and then it gives an error because it takes to much time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at your HTML in Firefox. It's filled with errors. Ie "line 1388 column 6 - Error: end tag for element "BODY" which is not open".

Go clean up your HTML, and if you still have the issue, come back and ask again.